# Execution environment selection on feature file or scenario level upon using Karate Run option from plugin

Tags: karate, vscode-extensions

To run karate tests against a particular test environment from config, we typically use karate.env either in the execution command or set this value in the runner file.

If we run individual scenario or feature file using Run/ Play option of the plugin, it typically runs against the default environment from config.

Is there a way to define the execution environment on the feature file or individual scenario level for standalone test execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the [official Karate extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=karatelabs.karate#run-options), this is supported as a paid-upgrade. See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Are there any future plans for supporting this feature in free version of plugin?

Comment: @rc22 we will consider it. meanwhile see this thread for workarounds. it may be possible to use a vs code launch config to do what you want: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-vscode-extension/issues/12